# C# Although radiobuton checked=false, when I run it, it comes as ticked

Tags: c#, asp.net, radio-button

I'm trying to make simple race game in c#. I have 4 radio buttons and their `checked` property is false. When I look to my code, I tried something like `radioButton1.checked=true` but when I run the program, the radiobutton1 is checked. How can I set it to false?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace at_yarisi
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();


            radioButton1.Checked = false;
            radioButton2.Checked = false;
            radioButton3.Checked = false;
            radioButton4.Checked = false;
        }

        int uzaklik1, uzaklik2, uzaklik3, uzaklik4, tahmin, skor = 0;
        Random x = new Random();
        private void YeniOyun()
        {
            timer1.Enabled= false;
            timer2.Enabled= false;
            pictureBox1.Left = 0;
            pictureBox2.Left = 0;
            pictureBox3.Left = 0;
            pictureBox4.Left = 0;
            label41.Text = "--";

            radioButton1.Checked = false;
            radioButton2.Checked = false;
            radioButton3.Checked = false;
            radioButton4.Checked = false;


        }


        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int genis1 = pictureBox1.Width;
            int genis2 = pictureBox2.Width;
            int genis3 = pictureBox3.Width;
            int genis4 = pictureBox4.Width;

            pictureBox1.Left += x.Next(15, 20);
            pictureBox2.Left += x.Next(15, 20);
            pictureBox3.Left += x.Next(15, 20);
            pictureBox4.Left += x.Next(15, 20);

            int bitis = label30.Left;
            // Yarıştırılan arabalar arasındaki en büyük uzaklığı hesapla
            int enBuyukUzaklik = Math.Max(Math.Max(pictureBox1.Left, pictureBox2.Left), Math.Max(pictureBox3.Left, pictureBox4.Left));

            // Hangi arabaların en önde olduğunu kontrol et
            List<int> ondekiArabalar = new List<int>();
            if (pictureBox1.Left == enBuyukUzaklik) ondekiArabalar.Add(1);
            if (pictureBox2.Left == enBuyukUzaklik) ondekiArabalar.Add(2);
            if (pictureBox3.Left == enBuyukUzaklik) ondekiArabalar.Add(3);
            if (pictureBox4.Left == enBuyukUzaklik) ondekiArabalar.Add(4);

            // Label'ı güncelle
            label41.Text = string.Join(", ", ondekiArabalar);

            if (genis1 + pictureBox1.Left >= bitis && genis2 + pictureBox2.Left != bitis && genis3 + pictureBox3.Left != bitis && genis4 + pictureBox4.Left != bitis)
            {
                timer1.Enabled = false;
                MessageBox.Show("The Cheetah won the race");

                if (tahmin == 1)
                {

                    skor += 1;
                    label40.Text = skor.ToString();
                }


            }
            else if (genis1 + pictureBox1.Left != bitis && genis2 + pictureBox2.Left >= bitis && genis3 + pictureBox3.Left != bitis && genis4 + pictureBox4.Left != bitis)
            {
                timer1.Enabled = false;
                MessageBox.Show("The Car won the race");


                if (tahmin == 2)
                {

                    skor += 1;
                    label40.Text = skor.ToString();
                }


            }
            else if (genis1 + pictureBox1.Left != bitis && genis2 + pictureBox2.Left != bitis && genis3 + pictureBox3.Left >= bitis && genis4 + pictureBox4.Left != bitis)
            {
                timer1.Enabled = false;
                MessageBox.Show("The Racer won the race");

                if (tahmin == 3)
                {


                    skor += 1;
                    label40.Text = skor.ToString();
                }



            }
            else if (genis1 + pictureBox1.Left != bitis && genis2 + pictureBox2.Left != bitis && genis3 + pictureBox3.Left != bitis && genis4 + pictureBox4.Left >= bitis)
            {
                timer1.Enabled = false;
                MessageBox.Show("The Jet won the race");
                if (tahmin == 4)
                {


                    skor += 1;
                    label40.Text = skor.ToString();
                }

            }

            if (pictureBox1.Left > pictureBox2.Left + 10 && pictureBox1.Left > pictureBox3.Left + 10 && pictureBox1.Left > pictureBox4.Left + 10)
            {
                label41.Text = "1";
            }
            if (pictureBox2.Left > pictureBox1.Left + 10 && pictureBox2.Left > pictureBox3.Left + 10 && pictureBox2.Left > pictureBox4.Left + 10)
            {
                label41.Text = "2";
            }
            if (pictureBox3.Left > pictureBox1.Left + 10 && pictureBox3.Left > pictureBox2.Left + 10 && pictureBox3.Left > pictureBox4.Left + 10)
            {
                label41.Text = "3";
            }
            if (pictureBox4.Left > pictureBox1.Left + 10 && pictureBox4.Left > pictureBox2.Left + 10 && pictureBox4.Left > pictureBox3.Left + 10)
            {
                label41.Text = "4";
            }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Enabled = true;

        }

        private void radioButton2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (radioButton2.Checked)
            {
                tahmin = 2;
            }
        }

        private void radioButton3_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (radioButton3.Checked)
            {
                tahmin = 3;
            }
        }

        private void radioButton4_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (radioButton4.Checked)
            {
                tahmin = 4;
            }
        }

        private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void button8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Enabled = true;

        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            YeniOyun();

        }

        private void button1_Click_2(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Trafik ışığı kodu başlangıcı
            if (timer2.Enabled)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("You cannot start a new transaction until the previous transaction is completed.");
                return;
            }

            label1.Text = "Kırmızı";
            label1.BackColor = Color.Red;
            timer2.Enabled = true;
            // Trafik ışığı kodu sonu


        }

        private void button2_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            YeniOyun();

        }

        private void label30_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void pictureBox4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void label25_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label1.BackColor = Color.Transparent;

            if (label1.Text == "Kırmızı")
            {
                label1.Text = "Yeşil";
                label1.BackColor = Color.Green;
                timer1.Enabled = true;
                timer2.Enabled = false;
            }
            else
            {
                label1.Text = "Kırmızı";
                label1.BackColor = Color.Red;
            }
        }

        private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {



        }

        private void radioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (radioButton1.Checked)
            {
                tahmin = 1;
            }
        }

        private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
            {
                timer1.Enabled = true;
            }
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            pictureBox1.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
            pictureBox2.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
            pictureBox3.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
            pictureBox4.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
          
            uzaklik1 = pictureBox1.Left;
            uzaklik2 = pictureBox2.Left;
            uzaklik3 = pictureBox3.Left;
            uzaklik4 = pictureBox4.Left;


            button1.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch;
            button1.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
            button1.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
            button2.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch;
            button2.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
            button2.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
            button1.FlatAppearance.MouseDownBackColor = Color.Transparent;
            button1.FlatAppearance.MouseOverBackColor = Color.Transparent;
            button2.FlatAppearance.MouseDownBackColor = Color.Transparent;
            button2.FlatAppearance.MouseOverBackColor = Color.Transparent;
            button1.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0;
            button2.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0;
        }

        private void label65_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

I tried to write `radiobutton1.checked=false` in form load event and in properties, i verified if `checked` property is false. but both didn't work

Comment: Why not put `radiobutton1.checked=false` in the constructor?

Comment: the constructor i.e. `public Form1()`

Comment: Oh sorry mb. I tried it too but didnt work

Comment: add all radio button inside GroupBox control. Look at here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.radiobutton?view=windowsdesktop-7.0

Comment: When the user selects one option button within a group, the others clear automatically. All RadioButton controls in a given container, such as a Form, constitute a group. To create multiple groups on one form, place each group in its own container, such as a GroupBox or Panel control.

Comment: RadioButton and CheckBox controls have a similar function: they offer choices a user can select or clear. The difference is that multiple CheckBox controls can be selected at the same time, but option buttons are mutually exclusive.

Comment: Can you write it as an answer? So i can confirm it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you place the RadioButtons on the form it will autoselect the one with lowest  Tab-index by design (because 1 "should always be selected")

However if you place them as child items inside a container control like the Panel or Group you need to manually set which one that should be selected.